# pandas_python_interpolate

Tags: python, python-2.x

Данный код запускаю в *jupyter* ну или в другом редакторе (это не важно) программа не работает. Запускаю в консоли, всё прекрасно интерполирует. 
В чем проблема?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2.1, np.nan, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8],'B': [.25, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 12.2, 14.4]})
df.interpolate()

print df
```

Comment: Консоль и jupiter/другие редакторы точно одну и ту же версию Питона используют? ОС какая? Когда программа "не работает", что она пишет, какие сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: Версия.
Версия, которая используется в консоле '2.7.11|Anaconda 2.4.1<64-bit>
В jupyter вывел тоже такую же версию 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 14:10:42) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

ОС:
ОС у меня Windows 7 64-х битная

Ошибки
Ошибок никаких не выдаёт просто функция interpolate() не работает
и NaN значения остаются NaN значениями.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
df.interpolate()
```

Нужно

```
df2 = df.interpolate()
```

`df2` будет копией `df` с интерполированными значениями.